# Update Facebook status without getting user and pass from a user

Tags: php, facebook

I need to publish in facebook wall , the site that I developing is a news portal, for this task I download php sdk and I create a new app.

I have a problem to login and feed, because I need that the server using a cron job list new articles that isn't publish and publish them.

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config); 
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

Always I getting a $uid = 0, I don't need that to show a login dialog because I need that the app that i create do this.

I was looking but I didn't find a way to do that. I see many examples but all need that the user login using a pop up dialog.

Comment: You would need to get the user to authenticate at some point before you push the job into a background worker (i.e. cron). Once you have authenticated the user you can use an OAuth token to handle logins.http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Answer (score 2):

You can't get facebook user if he doesn't give permissions to your application.

You should redirect (unknown) user to permissions dialog or show a permissions popup, with requesting publish_stream additional permission. When user grant your app requested permissions, you will have what you need: uid, access token and you will be able to publish posts.